# Send Only Active Sheet as PDF Attachment through GMail in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

Right now, my code is sending my entire Google Sheet file as a PDF attachment.  I am needing it, though, to only send my one tab entitled "PO Template".  Let me know if you can help:

```
function emailGoogleSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var email = ss.getRange("A19").getValue();
  var PO = ss.getRange("N3").getValue();
  var subject = "PO No. " + PO;
  var blob = 
DriveApp.getFileById(shs.getId()).getAs("Application/pdf");
  var body = "Install the <a href='http://www.labnol.org/email-
sheet'>Email Spreadsheet add-on</a> for one-click conversion.";
  blob.setName(ss.getName()+".pdf");
  if(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments:[blob]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's an adhoc method to do this. You'll have to resort to a workaround as suggested by this [github tutorial](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885):

```
// Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
```